# Volver dinámico un método sobre copia de imágenes en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código lo que hace es copiarme una imagen de mi origen a mi destino con un distinto nombre, ahorita lo tengo manual pero quisiera hacerlo dinamico ya que son muchas imagenes.. si alguien tiene alguna idea de como poder hacerlo dinamico, cabe mencionar que en un excel tengo la relacion del nombre con que se reenombrarian las imagenes

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        string antes = "rutaorigen/526.jpg";

        string despues = "rutadestino/1.png";

        System.IO.File.Copy(antes, despues);
    }
```

Comment: En rutaorigen estarían el resto de las imagenes?

Comment: asi es @Yussef ahi estaría el resto de las imagenes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener los archivos de una carpeta puedes usar [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-7.0)

```
string path_origen = "rutaorigen";
string path_destino = "rutadestino";
foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(path_origen))
{
     //string nuevo_nombre = GetNameFromExcel(file);
     File.Copy(file, $"{path_destino}/{nuevo_nombre}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //obtener las rutas de los directorios origen y destino
        FolderBrowserDialog sourceFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        FolderBrowserDialog targetFolderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();

        if (sourceFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (targetFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            return;
        }

        //obtener la información del directorio origen
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolderDialog.SelectedPath);

        //para todos los archivos del directorio copiar
        //file.FullName contiene la ruta completa del archivo
        //file.Name solo el nombre del archivo
        //GetFiles obtiene un array que convierto a lista por conveniencia
        //de objetos FileInfo que contienen información de los archivos
        dinfo.GetFiles().ToList().ForEach(file =>
        {
            File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(targetFolderDialog.SelectedPath, file.Name));
        });
```